# How to get the Bar Index of the Max Drawdown?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to get the bar index of the max drawdown for every trade and couldn't figure it out.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
maxArr = array.new_float()
entArr = array.new_int()
exArr = array.new_int()
diffArr = array.new_int()
biArr = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1

// calculate the absolute drawdown percentage
    drawdown = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(i)
    costBasis = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i)
    runup = strategy.closedtrades.max_runup(i)
    entindex = strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(i)
    exindex = strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(i)
    diff = exindex - entindex
    array.push(entArr,entindex)
    array.push(exArr,exindex)
    array.push(diffArr,diff)

    end = if math.max(drawdown,runup) == drawdown
        costBasis - drawdown
    else
        costBasis + runup

    array.push(maxArr,end)

//var float aa = 0 //used for another version
var int bb = 0
var int cc = 0
var int dd = 0

for j = 0 to array.size(maxArr) - 1
    //a = array.get(maxArr,j) //used for another version
    //aa := a //used for another version
    //b = array.get(entArr,j) //used for another version
    //bb := b //used for another version
    c = array.get(exArr,j)
    cc := c
    d = array.get(diffArr,j)
    dd := d

//var int sbi = bb //used for another version
//var int ebi = cc //used for another version
//var float hb = na //used for another version

//var int lb = cc - bb //used for another version

jj = (cc + ta.lowestbars(dd))
hh = bar_index==cc?jj:na

array.push(biArr,hh)

//plot(hh) //used for another version

biArr_string = str.tostring(biArr)
debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = biArr_string)
label.delete(debug[1])
```

I have only added the above part because I have 18 different versions of trying to figure it out and none have been successful. There are some additional variables which I have commented out as they are from different versions, so please ignore them.

Any help or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Added below the updated code based on @G.Lebret answer. I am getting an output that only shows an empty array.

```
biArr = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1

// calculate the absolute drawdown percentage
    drawdown = strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(i)

    var max_drawdown = 0.0
    var bar_index_max_drawdown = 0
    if strategy.closedtrades > 0
        if drawdown > max_drawdown
            max_drawdown := drawdown
            bar_index_max_drawdown := bar_index
    if strategy.opentrades == 0
        if max_drawdown != 0
        // Push to array
            array.push(biArr,bar_index_max_drawdown)
        // Reset values
        max_drawdown := 0.0

biArr_string = str.tostring(biArr)
debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = biArr_string)
label.delete(debug[1])
```

EDIT [26th January 2023]

I have used your code to find the bar index of the max drawdown, and it worked. While working on it, I had another idea and wanted to figure out the bar index when either the profit or the loss crosses 2% (just an example, the % can be anything). I tried different variations but feel the code below is the closest to anything that I could achieve that would bring me closer to my goal. However, when I use the code below, I get negative bar indices when using my strategy. So I tested it using the dummy strategy you provided below, and the bar indices for them are also incorrect. Basically the bar index provided is not the bar index when the profit or loss crosses 2%.

Below is the code, would appreciate if you could guide me on what I am doing incorrectly.

```
var number_of_trades = 0
var max_move = 2.0
var bar_index_max_move = 0
var tradeMax1 = 0.0
var array<int> moveBars = array.new_int()
maxArrb = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    cost = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)
    size = strategy.opentrades.size(i)
    profit = strategy.opentrades.profit(i)
    float tradeMax = math.abs(profit/(cost*size)*100)
    tradeMax1 := tradeMax

if ta.change(tradeMax1 >= max_move) and strategy.opentrades > 0
    max_move := tradeMax1
    bar_index_max_move := bar_index

if strategy.closedtrades > number_of_trades
    number_of_trades := number_of_trades + 1
    if max_move != 0
        array.push(moveBars,bar_index_max_move)
        // Reset values
        max_move := 2.0

for [j, bar] in moveBars
    int entryBar = strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(j) 
    int barsToMaxMove = bar - entryBar
    array.push(maxArrb, barsToMaxMove)

//Label and plot to check if the output of the bar index is correct
plot(array.size(maxArrb))
maxArrb_string = str.tostring(maxArrb)
debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = maxArrb_string)
label.delete(debug[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for loop is executed on each bar.
I think that on each loop, you delete your previous data.
You should test for the drawdown of the last trade only.
The best approach is to record the bar_index each time a trade is open and when the drawdown of the open trade is bigger.

```
var max_drawdown = 0.0
var bar_index_max_drawdown = 0
if strategy.opentrades > 0 // a trade is open
    if strategy.opentrades.max_drawdown(strategy.opentrades - 1) > max_drawdown
        max_drawdown := strategy.opentrades.max_drawdown(strategy.opentrades - 1)
        bar_index_max_drawdown := bar_index
if strategy.opentrades == 0 // no trades open
    if max_drawdown <> 0
        // Print the bar_index on the chart
        label.new(bar_index_max_drawdown, max_drawdown, str.tostring(bar_index_max_drawdown) )
        // Reset values
        max_drawdown := 0.0
```

[EDIT 21-01-2023]
The complete code (stupid strategy included for example)

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

var number_of_trades = 0
var max_drawdown = 0.0
var bar_index_max_drawdown = 0
if strategy.opentrades > 0 // a trade is open
    if strategy.opentrades.max_drawdown(strategy.opentrades - 1) > max_drawdown
        max_drawdown := strategy.opentrades.max_drawdown(strategy.opentrades - 1)
        bar_index_max_drawdown := bar_index
if strategy.closedtrades > number_of_trades // a trade just closed
    number_of_trades := number_of_trades + 1
    if max_drawdown != 0
        // Print the bar_index on the chart
        label.new(bar_index_max_drawdown, close*1.001, str.tostring(bar_index_max_drawdown) )
        // Reset values
        max_drawdown := 0.0
```

Example of result : 
[image]

The code print a label on the bar where the max draw down appears, and the label contains the index of this bar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the idea is that I want to figure out the bar index of the max drawdowns for all the closed trades and not only for the last trade.

The reason I want to get the bar index of the max drawdowns for all the closed trades is to eventually understand the count of bars until the max drawdowns, which in turn will help me estimate the risk of the strategy more quantitatively.

Please let me know if you would require me to elaborate further.

Comment: @DanielDsouza Yes I understand. My answer show you how to detect the last drawdown. You just need to record each drawdown the code find (instead of printing a label)  in an array to get a list of all your max drawdown.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you say. I will test your solution and implement it in my code. I will get back to you if it works. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hello @G.Lebret, I implemented and tested your solution in my code and I am getting an output that is just an empty array. Editing my original post to add the reworked code for your perusal. Please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly. Thank You

Comment: just try to add ‘var’ before biArr = array.new_int()

Comment: Did that and now I get "No Data", not even the empty array as before. Sorry for requesting for so much of your time.

Comment: @DanielDsouza I updated my answer with a complete working code. Hopes it helps

Comment: thank you for your time and patience. I have used the code exactly as you said and instead of a label, I have added the array.push function. And then printed a label which is a string of my array. The label just gives the last bar index in the whole label string (basically the same value). I have no idea what I am doing incorrectly with your code. However, I was on the Pine Script Q&A chat and I have found a solution.

So it will be alright if you don't want to spend more of your time on this solution.

Also, I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: I am trying to find the bar index based on another condition. I have used your solution and worked on it to try to find the solution based on my updated condition, but it doesn't work correctly. I have edited my original post with a post made today. Would appreciate if you could guide me.
Kind Regards,

Comment: @DanielDsouza You should not edit your first question to post another one. Please ask a new question, you will get help.

Comment: I realized my mistake and did post it as a new question. Here, is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/q/75253410/19957401 . Would appreciate your help. Kind Regards