# Find the Bar Index when Profit or Loss crosses a specified percentage

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to figure out the bar index when either the profit (absolute value) or the loss (absolute value) crosses 2% (just an example, the % can be anything). I tried different variations but feel the code below is the closest to anything that I could achieve that would bring me closer to my goal. However, when I use the code below, I get negative bar indices when using my strategy (*I have realized this happens because some of the open trades do not fulfil the first if condition and hence pick the bar index from the true condition for the previous open trade. I do not know how to rectify this issue*). Basically the bar index provided is not the bar index when the profit or loss crosses 2%.

Another issue I have noticed, which I cannot figure out - as the strategy enters when the bars open, if the condition of the profit or loss exceeding 2% has been met on that same bar, then the code does not capture this bar index. It captures the bar index when the 2% has been exceeded on another bar.

Below is the code, would appreciate if somebody would guide me on what I am doing incorrectly.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Testing", process_orders_on_close=false)

pine_dev(source, length) =>
    mean = ta.sma(source, length)
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        val = source[i]
        sum := sum + math.abs(val - mean)
    dev = sum/length

indicator = pine_dev(close,9)

percentile = (ta.percentrank(indicator,9))

if percentile <= 25
    strategy.entry("Enter Trade",strategy.long)

if percentile == 100
    strategy.close("Enter Trade",comment="Exit Trade")


var number_of_trades = 0
var max_move = 2.0
var bar_index_max_move = 0
var tradeMax1 = 0.0
var array<int> moveBars = array.new_int()
maxArrb = array.new_int()

for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    cost = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)
    size = strategy.opentrades.size(i)
    profit = strategy.opentrades.profit(i)
    float tradeMax = math.abs(profit/(cost*size)*100)
    tradeMax1 := tradeMax

if ta.change(tradeMax1 >= max_move) and strategy.opentrades > 0
    max_move := tradeMax1
    bar_index_max_move := bar_index

if strategy.closedtrades > number_of_trades
    number_of_trades := number_of_trades + 1
    if max_move != 0
        array.push(moveBars,bar_index_max_move)
        // Reset values
        max_move := 2.0

for [j, bar] in moveBars
    int entryBar = strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(j) 
    int barsToMaxMove = bar - entryBar
    array.push(maxArrb, barsToMaxMove)

//Label and plot to check if the output of the bar index is correct
plot(array.size(maxArrb))
maxArrb_string = str.tostring(maxArrb)
debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = maxArrb_string)
label.delete(debug[1])
```

Also, I have tried a variation where rather than using strategy.opentrades.profit, I have used strategy.opentrades.max_runup and strategy.opentrades.max_drawdown. Calculated the absolute max among them and tried to get the bar index when 2% is crossed, but that didn't help either.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Kind Regards,

Comment: The variable bar_index is not being updated inside the loop. bar_index should be replaced with i to correctly track the bar index when the trade's profit or loss crosses 2%.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don’t understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate with a sample code or some sort of guidance to relevant material?

Comment: Please edit your question with a complete code. We can't test it because there is no strategy.entry in your code. Also, please elaborate on what you are looking for... not so clear for me

Comment: @G.Lebret I have added the complete code with strategy.entry. Also, I have elaborated what I am trying to do and what I am seeking. Hope this helps. Would add more information if you have any more queries. Looking forward to hearing from you.